# Зачем в .NET типы данных разделили на ссылочные и значимые?

Tags: c#, .net, дизайн-языка

Зачем в .NET типы данных разделили на ссылочные и значимые?

Comment: Сформулируйте правильно вопрос и получите половину ответа. А чтобы сформулировать вопрос, достаточно почитать любую серьезную литературу по C#.

Comment: см. [Основные характеристики типов значений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Comment: @Stack, Я знаю все эти характеристики, знаю все различия ссылочных и значимых типов, как и где они хранятся, как передаются и тд. Мне просто интересно  какая идеология разделения типов на 2 группы? Почему разработчики .Net решили сделать именно так?

Comment: А за что минусы? Хороший вопрос на самом деле. Вопросы типа «почему?» намного важнее вопросов типа «как?».

Comment: @VladD Как думаете, стоит убрать C# .и NET и сделать вопрос общим для всех языков?

Comment: @KromStern: Насколько я понимаю, в C++ такой концепции нет вовсе, там все типы по поведению являются типами-значениями. Так что общей значимости наверное нет. А в Java нету пользовательских типов-значений, только примитивы типа `int`. (А `Integer` уже ведёт себя как ссылочный тип.)

Comment: _"Почему разработчики .Net решили сделать именно так?"_ -- надо представить задачи. например: есть область памяти. и надо копировать ее целиком. как такое назовем? назвали value type. а вот есть другая область памяти в heap. ее не копируем, а надо просто передать ее адрес. как такое назовем? назвали reference type. и еще: есть память в стеке потока, она освобождается, но надо часть сохранить, т.е. копировать в heap, а также нужно из heap копировать в стек потока. как такое назовем? назвали boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Различие между ссылочными типами и типами-значениями на самом деле семантическое. Оно не в том, выделяется ли память в куче или нет (язык имеет право любой из объектов располагать в любой памяти, и делает это: например, типы-значения, попавшие в замыкание, будут «подняты» до кучи).

Различие состоит в семантике *равенства* и *копирования*.

Давайте посмотрим на пример. Вот у вас есть число 5. Это число — одно и то же, вне зависимости от того, как вы его получили. Если вы увеличите 5 на 1, вы не *измените* при этом само число 5, вы просто получите *новое* число. Когда вы копируете число в другую переменную, эта новая переменная живёт своей жизнью, не зависящей от старого числа.

Теперь, пусть у вас есть объект, допустим, `СписокПокупок`. Этот объект ведёт себя совсем по-другому. Если вы создадите *новый* `СписокПокупок`, он будет отличаться от уже существующего: вы можете добавить товар в новый список, а в старом он при этом не появится. С другой стороны, когда вы копируете ссылку на список покупок в другую переменную, то вы продолжаете при это работать с *тем же* списком.

Иными словами: у объектов типа списка покупок есть *индивидуальность*. А у объектов типа числа такой индивидуальности нет, они ничем не отличаются друг от друга.

Так вот: объекты, которые ведут себя как число, и называются объектами-значениями. А объекты с индивидуальностью называются ссылочными объектами.

Все остальные технические подробности служат лишь для реализации этой самой различной семантики. Например, объекты-значения чаще всего располагаются в стеке потому, что их *можно* расположить там: ведь у них никому не интересен конкретный экземпляр, поэтому за пределы метода можно выдать *копию*. А значит, оригинал можно держать на стеке (так эффективнее).

Дополнительная литература: Eric Lippert. *The Stack Is An Implementation Detail*: [Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/), [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/).

Comment: про семантику вы верно говорите, но ни что не мешает передавать копию значения объекта в куче равно как передавать value-типы по ссылке. Так что это ни коим образом не отменяет проблему производительности возникающую при реализации той или иной семантики. Кроме того к один и тот же объект в разных контекстах может иметь разную семантику.

Comment: опять же, индивидуальность объекта никак не влияет на семантику равенства и копирования. Другой вопрос, что обеспечить синхронное изменение, если того требует семантика, гораздо проще если есть ссылка на один объект, а не множество его копий.

Comment: @rdorn: Дело в том, что копия ссылочного объекта практически никогда не нужна. Если у вас есть объект «человек», то склонировав его, вы получите _другого_ человека. Можно, конечно, пожертвовать семантикой, и прихлопнуть лишнюю копию, но суть в том, что объекты с индивидуальностью так себя обычно не ведут. Поэтому клонирование ссылочных типов практически никогда не нужно.

Comment: @rdorn: Точно так же можно передавать типы-значения по ссылке, но снова-таки, поскольку их можно копировать, то обычно так и делают. Разницы нет. (За исключением ужасных, отвратительных _изменяемых_ объектов-значений, да.)

Comment: @rdorn: Мне кажется, индивидуальность объекта влияет на семантику равенства! Если у вас есть два набора координат `(2, 3)` и `(2, 3)`, они очевидно равны. А вот если у вас есть один человек `{ name: "Александр", surname: "Иванов" }` и другой человек `{ name: "Александр", surname: "Иванов" }`, то это всё же два разных человека, они не «равны». Для объекта «с индивидуальностью», **клон объекта не есть сам объект**!

Comment: `(За исключением ужасных, отвратительных изменяемых объектов значений, да.)` порадовало. Применительно к координатам не соглашусь. две точки могут одновременно относиться к разным объектам и при этом иметь одинаковые координаты, и далеко не всегда в таком случае их можно заменить одним объектом или просто значениями.

Comment: @rdorn: Well, в таком случае это не самостоятельный объект, а пол-объекта, для семантической самостоятельности ещё нужен некий идентификатор того, к чему координата относится. Окей, выкинем тот пример, возьмём абстрактное комплексное число, состоящее из действительной и мнимой части.

Comment: еще раз обращаю внимание, что я не спорю о наличии и важности семантических различий. Но в основе конкретной реализации почти всегда лежит производительность, т.к. любую семантику можно реализовать минимум 3-мя способами - правильно, не правильно и как в армии =)

Comment: @rdorn: Это да. Кроме того, и простым программистам иногда приходится жертвовать семантикой ради производительности в сложных случаях. Видел кучу статей по «оптимизации .NET», где центральным советом было наплевать на семантику и пользоваться структурами как можно больше, чуть ли не всегда. (Лучи ненависти им от меня: оптимизировать нужно bottleneck, определённый при профилировании.)

Comment: @VladD _"если у вас есть один человек { name: "Александр", surname: "Иванов" }"_ -- т.е. есть человек и запись о человеке. и клонов записи может быть много. например, копия номера телефона Иванова может быть у очень многих.  _"клон объекта не есть сам объект!"_ -- для valuetype так и есть. например, `int a = 1; int b = a;` -- это разные участки памяти. но для строк - нет. var a = "1"; var b = (string) a.Clone();`  -- это один и тот же объект. т.к. `String.IsInterned(b) == b`  // true

Comment: @Stack: Да, конечно. Информации о человеке может быть много, она по сути тип-значение. Но у нас же объектно-ориентированное программирование, да? И кроме информации о человеке у нас вполне может быть тип, представляющий _самого_ человека. Он-то и есть ссылочный тип, он и обладает индивидуальностью.

Comment: @Stack: То, что строки, хотя и являются по сути значениями, ведут себя отчасти как ссылочные типы — та самая жертва правильным дизайном во имя оптимальности имплементации. Замечание насчёт клона не вполне понял, к сожалению.

Comment: @VladD _"Но у нас же объектно-ориентированное программирование, да?"_ -- да, если на c#. 
_"у объектов типа числа такой индивидуальности нет, они ничем не отличаются друг от друга."_ -- `typeof(int).IsValueType = true`, но можно создать свой тип, например, `struct S { public int K; public int V; }` -- typeof(S).IsValueType = true. при этом `var a = new S {K=1, V=1}; var b = a;` -- в `b` оказывается копия. а дальше `b.K = 2;` --  `a` и `b` отличаются/разные.

Comment: @Stack: Ну так, вы ж поменяли `b`. Сравните: `var a = 5; var b = a; b++;` — `a` и `b` тоже отличаются.

Comment: @VladD _"Ну так, вы ж поменяли b."_ -- да, точно также вы меняете, когда предложили "добавить товар". наверное, я что-то не понимаю про "индивидуальность".

Comment: @Stack: Ну, если у меня есть заказ, и я добавляю в него товар, это _всё тот же мой заказ_ (я имею в виду с точки зрения реального мира). О нём можно говорить как о сущности, которая внутри меняется, но остаётся той же сущностью. А о числе, которое поменялось, никто не говорит как о _той же_ сущности: `5` всегда есть `5`. [Техническая составляющая: изменение сущности ссылочного типа по одной ссылке на неё видно по любой другой ссылке. В отличие от.]

Comment: @VladD _"О нём можно говорить как о сущности, которая внутри меняется, но остаётся той же сущностью."_ -- ок. согласен. _"изменение сущности ссылочного типа по одной ссылке на неё видно по любой другой ссылке"_ -- т.к. при `=` reference type не копируется, в отличие от value type. но value type можно передать по ссылке так `var a = new S {K=1, V=1};` `void fn(ref S s) { s.K=11; }` `fn(ref a);` `a.K` == 11  // true

Comment: @Stack: Это да, для типов-значений добавили ещё и новую семантику «ссылка на тип-значение», оно же `ref`. Я думаю, это сделано больше для совместимости с C++ и стилем мышления программистов, пришедших оттуда. В принципе, правильнее было бы наверное обрабатывать типы-значения чистыми функциями, и возвращать новое значение. Но для этого сразу нужна поддержка возврата множественных результатов, которая появится вроде бы в C# 7. Так что это особенности переходного периода :) Плюс, разумеется, повышение производительности (о чём говорится в ответе @rdorn) в тех случаях, когда она необходима.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем разделили? Потому что это связано с вычислительной архитектурой. И что бы тут про "семантическое различие" не рассказывали, всё дело именно в вычислителе (процессоре). Есть три основных места хранения числа (абсолютно вся информация в компьютере представлена в виде чисел), каждому из которых соответствует способ адресации и, условно, тип данных:

1. Регистр процессора. Регистровая адресация используется для выполнения математических операций (никаких других операций нет), либо в качестве временного места хранения для ускорения доступа. Любой тип данных (и значимый, и ссылочный). В процессоре обрабатываются как сами данные, так и адреса.
2. Ячейка памяти, адресуемая регистром процессора. Непосредственная адресация. Значимый тип данных.
3. Ячейка памяти содержит адрес другой ячейки памяти (и так далее рекурсивно). Косвенная адресация. Ссылочный тип данных.

Это суть, основа основ. Естественно, что один способ адресации может быстренько перейти в другой. При косвенной адресации процессор извлекает из ячейки памяти адрес другой ячеки памяти и получает прямой доступ к значениям, которые там хранятся.

Поскольку такая вычислительная архитектура практически единственная (может быть, процессоры более простой архитектуры просто не выпускаются), то значимые и ссылочные типы данных есть везде, а не только в .NET, только могут по разному называться.

Дальше возникает использование стека для значимых типов данных и кучи для ссылочных, подпрограммы управления кучей, правила для разных типов данных и т. д. и т. п., о чём красиво расписано в других ответах.

А поскольку, по большому счёту, никаких других способов обработки информации не придумали, то и все математические (информационные) модели строятся с ориентацией на эту архитектуру.