# Почему сравнения возвращают различные результаты?

Tags: c#, консоль, if

```
static bool Compare0()
{
    return new byte() == new byte();
}

static bool Compare1()
{
    return new byte[0] == new byte[0];
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Compare0());
    Console.WriteLine(Compare1());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Почему `Compare0()` возвращает `True`, а `Compare1()` - `False`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конструкция `new byte()` создает экземпляр типа `byte`, проинициализированный нулем. `byte` -- это структура, а следовательно, это значимый тип. По умолчанию все значимые типы сравниваются по значению. Поскольку два экземпляра проинициализированы одинаковым значением, `Compare0()` возвращает `True`.

Конструкция `new byte[0]` создает пустой массив типа `byte`. Массив  -- это ссылочный тип. По умолчанию экземпляры ссылочных типов равны, только если их ссылки равны, т.е. экземпляры указывают на один и тот же объект. Поскольку два экземпляра массива -- это два разных объекта в памяти, `Compare1()` возвращает `False`.

Подробнее о значимых и ссылочных типах можно почитать [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488666/106).