# Чем отличается структура от класса?

Tags: классы, struct

В чем отличие структуры от класса?

Comment: В каком языке/технологии? В общем случае оба понятия достаточно широки.

Comment: @defaultlocale не могли бы вы обяснить на примере c# и c++

Comment: Это два разных вопроса. По C# посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488487 По C++ насколько понимаю вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420635/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем class отличается от struct?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420635/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-class-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-struct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс - это данные и методы для работы с этими данными.

Структра схожа с классом, она так же может иметь в себе перечень неких данных и даже методов.

Но: структура не поддерживает наследование, имплементирование, ее можно объявить внутри класса, структура является дополнительным сборным типом данных.

*Структура (struct) является типом значения. При создании структуры переменная, которой присвоена структура, содержит фактические данные этой структуры. Если структура присваивается новой переменной, все данные копируются. Таким образом, новая переменная и исходная переменная содержат две отдельные копии одинаковых данных. Изменения, внесенные в одну копию, не влияют на другую.*

*В общем случае классы используются для моделирования более сложного поведения или для таких данных, которые будут изменяться после создания объекта класса. Структуры лучше подходят для небольших структур данных, информация в которых не должна изменяться после создания структуры.*

Подробная инфа - **https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/**